# A Custom Function Got An Unexpected Keyword Argument

Tags: python

I have module for printing nested lists in another list:

```
import sys

def custom_print(the_list, indent=False, level=0, fh=sys.stdout):

    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            custom_print(each_item, indent, level+1, fh)
        else:
            if indent:
                for tab_stop in range(level):
                    print("\t", end="", file=fh)
            print(each_item, file=fh)
```

I try to import this module in a program which I use for printing a text file into two separate lists. And then I want to write these lists to two files on my hard disk.

```
import listsprint

man = []
other = []

try:
    data = open("speech.txt")
    for each_line in data:        
        try:
            (role, line_spoken) = each_line.split(":", 1)
            line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
            if role == "Man":
                man.append(line_spoken)
            elif role == "Other Man":
                other.append(line_spoken)               
        except ValueError:
            pass
    data.close()

except IOError:
    print("The data file is missing")

try:
    with open("man_data.txt", "w") as man_file:
        listsprint.custom_print(man, file=man_file)
    with open("other_data.txt", "w") as other_file:
        listsprint.custom_print(other, file=other_file)

except IOError as err:
    print("File error: " + str(err))
```

But when I run the program, an exception occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....\....\Desktop\drills\chapter3\speech.py", line 26, in <module>
    listsprint.custom_print(man, file=man_file)    
TypeError: custom_print() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

Comment: Typo: you should have used `fh` instead of `file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, your `custom_print` function doesn't accept a `file` argument. Did you perhaps mean to use `fh` instead?